# Can you date / marry a girl that has your sister's name?

Tags: marriage

In Hindu Scripture, do they anywhere talk about ethics behind dating / marrying a girl that has the same name as your sister? Is it okay or considered a sin or just immoral?

Comment: What makes you think it would be sinful?

Comment: @CDR the ***"name"*** ?